# Ranking of multi-indexed DF

Tags: python, pandas

I have a multi-indexed DF with the following structure:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({(2014, 'value'): {('AR', 0): 1.2420, ('AR', 1): 0.1802,('BR', 0): 1.3,('BR', 1): 0.18}})
>>> print df

      2014
      value
AR 0  1.2420
   1  0.1802
BR 0  1.3000
   1  0.1800
```

My goal is to add a column 'rank', that contains the ranking of the countries (AR & BR) for 0 & 1 in descending order. The desired result would be something like:

```
            2014          
            value   rank 
iso   id
AR    0     1.2420  2      
      1     0.1802  1    
BR    0     1.3     1    
      1     0.18    2
```

My initial approach was to reset the index:

```
>>> df = df.reset_index()
>>> print df

       level_0   level_1   2014
                           value
0      AR        0         1.2420
1      AR        1         0.1802
2      BR        0         1.3000
3      BR        1         0.1800
```

And then add the 'rank' column using a groupby and rank:

```
>>> df[2014, 'gr'] =  df.groupby(['level_1'])[2014, 'value'].rank(ascending=False)
```

This results, however, in:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/groupby.py", line 2990, in __getitem__
    if len(self.obj.columns.intersection(key)) != len(key):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/index.py", line 3774, in intersection
    result_names = self.names if self.names == other.names else None
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'names'
```

Am I on the right track, another approach I should consider?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So rank is coming from `value` right? I think this is what you want:

```
In [13]: df.groupby(level=1).rank(ascending=False)
Out[13]: 
      2014
     value
AR 0     2
   1     1
BR 0     1
   1     2
```

which you can set with `df['rank'] = df.groupby(level=1).rank(ascending=False)`

Comment: Thanks. That was simpler than I thought. I set the value slightly differently : ```df[(2014, 'rank')] = df.groupby(level=1).rank(ascending=False)```